# Flagged answer and declined with -11 score

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged an answer with negative score as low quality.

Is it fine to flag a meta-post as low quality depending on negative score?

Please guide me to correct thing .

Comment: "This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed." - This does not equate to a *wrong* answer.

Comment: Flagging a post as VLQ shouldn't be dependent on _only_ its score.

Comment: @MoathHowari See J. Steen's comment on when you should flag as VLQ. If you link to the answer in question, we may be able to better tell you why it was declined (apart from the response you got) and what would be an appropriate action. Also, if you state *why* you thought it should be flagged as VLQ

Comment: @MoathHowari, but from what you said in your post, the only reason you thought to flag the post was _because_ it had -4 as a score.

Comment: You didn't *say* only on score but the wording of your post makes it seem that way. Please update with more information such as what I suggested.

Comment: @gunr2171 sir i didn't use only in my question

Comment: Yeah so what are the *other* reasons? That you did not mention any other reason gives us the impression that score was the only criteria in your determining what to flag as VLQ.

Comment: @BoltClock sir the answer was deleted already i can't open it to tell you what .

Comment: You mean you don't even *remember* why you flagged the answer to begin with?

Comment: @MoathHowari, VLQ flagging, when done correctly, is done sparingly. So I hope you would remember _something_ about the post.

Comment: @MoathHowari, and we are saying "_why_ was it low quality?" Ignore the votes on the post, a VLQ flag needs to be about its content.

Comment: Sorry, but if you're not going to pay attention when flagging, then I'd rather you not do it at all. Flags are not something to be taken lightly, or just cast-and-forget.

Comment: No, we are not asking you to say the answer was a good answer. I'm not sure where you got that impression. We are asking you however to: 1) read posts before flagging them, 2) be paying enough attention when you are flagging an answer to remember something, *anything* about it, 3) realize that voting is different on meta, among other criticisms you've garnered.

Comment: Some people just want to watch the world burn..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I declined your flag.

I also declined another flag on the post that claimed it was 'not an answer'.

Regardless of how many people agree with [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251785/16587), it's still an answer.

It's also not 'Very Low Quality'.  Very Low Quality has a very specific meaning:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Or [as Jeff Atwood once put it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606):

> Whereas a downvote means "maybe this user is just having a bad day", a flag for low quality means **this post, and possibly this user, are totally stinking up the joint and need to be ejected from the premises ASAP.** (empahsis original)

An answer you disagree with (or one that accrues a lot of downvotes on Meta) does not necessarily mean it's very low quality.

If you flag an answer as "very low quality", we have two options:

1. Delete it.
2. Do nothing.

We're not going to delete bad answers -- the community can do that. We're only going to delete answers that are so atrocious in their formatting or content that we have no other choice but to delete them.

Answer (score 9):

Votes on meta are sometimes used to express disagreement with the post. A low score can therefore mean that a small proportion of the community, who've read the answer so far, don't necessarily agree with the opinions put forth in the answer.

By asking for something to be unilaterally deleted by a moderator you're censoring discussion for no reason whatsoever. If you have something to say, then *please* say it! You get to have your opinions as does every one else and you can disagree by commenting, downvoting or adding your own answer.

Please **do not** flag things if you haven't read them, if you're doing it because of the score or for any reason other than that described in the flag options (i.e. it doesn't attempt to answer the question). It'd be better, quite frankly, if the low quality flag reason was removed from meta. There's no point in it existing and the reasons for it existing can be covered by other options. Forget it exists.