# I got really annoying comments on an old negative score question I have asked

Tags: discussion, comments, spam

A question I asked: [*Flagged answer and declined with -11 score*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251813/flagged-answer-and-declined-with-11-score).

First thing I shouldn't have asked this question.

Second thing why I'm still getting comments on it telling me this is an ironic.
[image]

I liked the last joke I guess when he/she said:

`It will be more ironic if someone flags this question due to 11 downvotes`

Just wondering is meta-Stack Overflow the correct place to make jokes.

And really I wish this question gets removed.

Thanks Meta.

Comment: it will be nice by adding comment on voting down :P

Answer (score 9):

Jokes are more appropiate for Meta than the regular site. However, if a comment doesn't add anything of value to the post it's comment on, then you can always just flag it as ***not constructive***, and it'll likely be removed sometime between 6 seconds and 8 months.

Comment: @Moath, though keep in mind, removing the comment just increases the chances that someone else will come along, notice the irony and comment again.

Comment: Also, on Meta moderators are more likely to decline comment flags than on the main site in my experience.

Comment: haha 6 **seconds** and 8 **months** :P